# Angular 6 - unable to subscribe to data returned from a service

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6, observable

I am trying to build a simple cache service in Angular; a service with a simple setter/getter function that different components can fetch data from.

Unfortunately when subscribing to this service to get the data, the subscribe callback is never called and the data is not retrieved.

*catch-service.service.js*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, from } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CacheService {

  cacheData: Observable<any>;

  constructor() { }

  setCacheData(data) {
    this.cacheData = new Observable(data)
  }

  getCacheData() :Observable<any> {
    return from(this.cacheData);
  }
}
```

*component.component.js*

```
...
export class SomeComponent {

  constructor(private cacheService: CacheService) { }

  data = null;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cacheService.getCacheData().subscribe(resp => {
      console.log(resp);
      this.data = resp;
    });
  }
...
```

I have injected the service in the module class and there are no compilation errors. The data in the component is just never set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like below

```
   export class CacheService {

     //create a method to set and get the cache 
     cacheData: Observable<any>
     setCache: (cachedata: any) {
          var newObservable = new Observable(observer => {
            observer.next(cachedata);
            observer.complete();
          });
          this.cacheData=newObservable;

    }
    getCacheData() :Observable<any>{
        return this.cacheData;
    }
```

On your component you can subscribe like below.

```
service.getCacheData().susbcribe((data)=>{
    //here you will get
});
```

You can also check the below answer how's observable working

[How create observable with parameters in Angular 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52416621/how-create-observable-with-parameters-in-angular-6/52417115#52417115)

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide data in `cacheData`.

use this an example.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  cacheData: Observable<any> = new Observable(observer => {
    observer.next(1)
    observer.next(2)
    observer.next(3)
    observer.next(4)
  })

  ngOnInit() {
    this.cacheData.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data)
      }
    )
  }
}
```

in there, you create a new `Observable` from ngrx library, which comes with angular.

And then set values you gonna consume (with `observer.next()`) once you subscribe to      `cacheData` property.

`observer.next()` can receive as arguments.

- Boolean
- Number
- String
- Function
- Object
- Array
- null
- undefined

For a more closer look, https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/observables/.

Comment: How would I go on creating a setter function in this service? I can't hard code the data into the server

Comment: you can do what i specify, to assure that there is no problem with the front-end. And then proceed with the backend.

Comment: Oh I see nvm then

Comment: Thank you, I just didn't know how to apply .next as a setter. Code-EZ helped me understand